# Missing server side dependencies and MissingSetupFile error with missing Site

Tags: powershell, health-analyzer

A while ago I deployed a feature to my site that included a JavaScript file.  I have since removed the file from the feature.  I have also deleted and recreated sites within the mysite webapp.

I have the following error

> [MissingSetupFile] File
>   [Features\MysitePerms_Site_ApplyCustomMasterPage\jQuery\jquery-1111min.js] is referenced
>   [1](http://get-spscripts.com/2011/06/diagnosing-missingsetupfile-issues-from.html) times in the database [MySite_Content], but is not installed on the current farm.
>   Please install any feature/solution which contains this file. One or more setup files
>   are referenced in the database [MySite_Content], but are not installed on the current
>   farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these files.

I followed the advice here: ( [Diagnose MissingWebPart and MissingAssembly issues from the SharePoint Health Analyzer using PowerShell](http://get-spscripts.com/2011/06/diagnosing-missingsetupfile-issues-from.html) )
 which resulted in the following output:

> Id       :
>   SiteId   :
>   DirName  :
>   LeafName :
>   WebId    :
>   ListId   :
>
> Id       : a46e3a53-af2a-4a3c-9c52-dd903dee7929
>   SiteId   : 7f507741-ec91-43db-bb8e-334f29f2458c
>   DirName  : personal/farm/SiteAssets
>   LeafName : jquery-1111min.js
>   WebId    : 1cc9837e-1f88-46a7-b9ac-35b3cef02647
>   ListId   :
>
> Id       : 2438ba11-cb23-4553-8b1b-0ad124ecfe1e
>   SiteId   : dc717951-79b3-4c6f-9e1d-6c0a7f96bb6d
>   DirName  : personal/jdoe/SiteAssets
>   LeafName : jquery-1111min.js
>   WebId    : 3b17c03a-9659-47f9-a8a4-0a0cbab593c6
>   ListId   :
>
> Id       : 92b88df5-6da5-406c-8869-02e2c93cb88f
>   SiteId   : 4d71f0a2-9011-493b-a2f7-752488eaa208
>   DirName  : SiteAssets
>   LeafName : jquery-1111min.js
>   WebId    : 138ca247-3953-4d1f-ab20-cb9a062720e0
>   ListId   :

But when I search for the Site and Webs in these results via:

```
$site = Get-SPSite -Limit all | 
   where { $_.Id -eq "7f507741-ec91-43db-bb8e-334f29f2458c" }
$web = $site | Get-SPWeb -Limit all | 
   where { $_.Id -eq "1cc9837e-1f88-46a7-b9ac-35b3cef02647" }
$web.Url
```

nothing is returned (this code is just for the first result).  It seems that the Sites and Webs that are referencing the missing file no longer exist. Yet there is still a record in the AllDocs database.

I know I cannot touch the DB.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Beuller...?  Beuller?

Answer (score 0):

Use a PowerShell command to remove the setup files using Id, SiteId and WebId provided by your output.

```
#File Information
$setupFileID = "xxxxxx"
$siteID = "xxxxxx"
$WebID = "xxxxxx"

#Get file
$site = Get-SPSite -Identity $siteID
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity $WebID -Site $siteID
$file = $web.GetFile([GUID]$setupFileID)

#Report on location
$filelocation = "{0}{1}" -f ($site.WebApplication.Url).TrimEnd("/"), $file.ServerRelativeUrl
Write-Host "Found file location:" $filelocation

#Delete the file, the Delete() method bypasses the recycle bin
$file.Delete()

$web.dispose()
$site.dispose()
```

**References:**

- [MissingSetupFile error while migration from SharePoint 2010 to 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/238038/missingsetupfile-error-while-migration-from-sharepoint-2010-to-2013)
- https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dawiese/2017/05/09/post-upgrade-cleanup-missing-server-side-dependencies/