# MissingSetupFile error while migration from SharePoint 2010 to 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin

I have done migration through content db attach method from share point 2010 to 2013 but in 2013 QA while running below command I got error, will it affect my migration or can I ignore this-now I have to take backup of this site collection and restore on production  webapplication.I have tried to find orphaned feature list in this site collection but did not get anything.

Test-SPContentDatabase -Name "db_name" -WebApplication "webapp_url"

Error_Category        : MissingSetupFile
Error           : True
UpgradeBlocking : False
Message         : File [Layouts\1033\styles\core.css] is referenced [1] times
                  in the database
                  [db_name], but exists
                  only under Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 setup
                  folder. Consider upgrading the feature/solution which
                  contains this file to the latest version.
Remedy          : One or more setup files are referenced in the database
                  [db_name, but are not
                  installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or
                  solution which contains these files.

Answer (score 1):

For the error , you can new a SQL query to find out the detail information of set up files:

```
USE WSS_Content_MissingAssembly_Snapshot

SELECT id, SiteID, DirName, LeafName, WebId, ListId
FROM AllDocs (NOLOCK) where SetupPath = 'Layouts\1033\styles\core.css'
```

Then use PowerShell command to remove the setup files which provided by above output .

```
#File Information
$setupFileID = "xxxxxx"
$siteID = "xxxxxx"
$WebID = "xxxxxx"

#Get file
$site = Get-SPSite -Identity $siteID
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity $WebID -Site $siteID
$file = $web.GetFile([GUID]$setupFileID)

#Report on location
$filelocation = "{0}{1}" -f ($site.WebApplication.Url).TrimEnd("/"), $file.ServerRelativeUrl
Write-Host "Found file location:" $filelocation

#Delete the file, the Delete() method bypasses the recycle bin
$file.Delete()

$web.dispose()
$site.dispose()
```

Reference : https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dawiese/2017/05/09/post-upgrade-cleanup-missing-server-side-dependencies/ .